# Query for replacing one field with the value of corresponding field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a table called **emp**:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ name ║ fathersid ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║  a   ║    2      ║
║  2 ║  s   ║   null    ║
║  3 ║  d   ║    1      ║
║  4 ║  f   ║    3      ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════════╝
```

I want to print the name corresponding with its father's name.

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT name,
    (SELECT name FROM emp WHERE father_id = id)
FROM emp
```

Is this correct?

If not, then what is the right answer?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: where is father table? post expected result

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle here? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its almost correct, you need to alias the tables so the reader will know you are comparing the inner query to the outer query :

```
SELECT t.NAME,
       (SELECT s.name FROM emp s where s.id = t.father_id) as Father_name
FROM emp t
```

You can do this with a join:

```
SELECT t.name,s.name as Father_Name
FROM emp t
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp s
 ON(t.father_id = s.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to solve this type of problem using a self-join:

```
SELECT e1.name AS name, COALESCE(e2.name, 'Not Available') AS fatherName
FROM emp e1 LEFT JOIN emp e2
    ON e1.fathersid = e2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can use a hierachical query (which only requires a single table scan - compared to using joins or correlated sub-queries which require multiple table scans):

```
SELECT name,
       PRIOR name AS fathers_name
FROM   emp
START WITH       fathersid = NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = fathersid;
```